# jQuery .ajax val disable prevent this page from creating additional dialogs in alert

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

Need to get 3 Select val

select 1 course 
select 2 course date
select 3 course place

when i change select 1
it's show select 2 and 3

i face error when i try to get any select values when i try to alert val this message appear
prevent this page from creating additional dialogs

Comment: Can you recreate you problem in JSFiddle?

Comment: Does [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgSAD/) also reproduce your issue?

Comment: Not working, my code (Your JS code is valid.)

The error when i try to get val using $.ajax, if if comment ajax when select option .change it work good
i think error in $.ajax when sending val from page to  page

Comment: Thank you for trying to helping me, resolved by removing beforeSend in $.ajax when submit values,

Comment: **UPDATE** Resolved, the problem from double include js file